# How to add -std=c++11 or -std=GNU++11 in the given make file of octane etk sample embedded file of IMPINJ Reader R420?

Tags: c++, c++11, makefile

I am trying to include PAHO MQTT C++ library in the octane etk sample application(which is in C++) provided by [IMPINJ](https://support.impinj.com/hc/en-us/articles/202755288-Speedway-Revolution-Embedded-Development-Tools-and-Sample-Application-ETK-).

I have followed the steps which is given in the impinj portal to make the sample application and I am able to read the tag information, whereas when I try to include the PAHO MQTT library in the sample application and when i make the provided sample application by impinj, it says

```
root@mindlogic-VirtualBox:/home/user/octane_etk_sample-6.0.0.240# make
mkdir -p ./bin
g++ \
    -m32 -Wno-write-strings \
    -Iinclude \
    speedway_embedded_example.cpp \
    -Llib -lltkcpp_x86 -lltkcppimpinj_x86 -lxml2_x86 \
    -L/usr/bin -ldl -lssl -lcrypto \
    -o bin/speedwayr_x86
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/chrono:35:0,
                 from /usr/local/include/mqtt/types.h:29,
                 from /usr/local/include/mqtt/async_client.h:29,
                 from speedway_embedded_example.cpp:23:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/c++0x_warning.h:32:2: error: #error This file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011 standard. This support is currently experimental, and must be enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options.
 #error This file requires compiler and library support for the \
  ^
In file included from include/ltkcpp.h:41:0,
                 from speedway_embedded_example.cpp:19:
include/version.inc:1:21: error: too many decimal points in number
 #define VERSION_STR 10.34.0.0
                     ^
In file included from /usr/local/include/mqtt/async_client.h:29:0,
                 from speedway_embedded_example.cpp:23:
/usr/local/include/mqtt/types.h:37:7: error: expected nested-name-specifier before ‘byte’
 using byte = uint8_t;
```

Can anyone help me out to enable the C++11?

Below is the content of MakeFile,

```
SOURCES = speedway_embedded_example.cpp
LIB_DIR = /usr/bin
MPNJ_LIB_DIR = lib
HEADER_DIR = include

ETK_DEFAULT_INSTALL_DIR = /home/etk/impinj_etk
INSTALL_TOOL_HELP = \
"Failed to find the arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ compiler." \
"Please make sure that /home/etk/impinj_etk/arm-toolchain/bin is in your PATH."
INSTALL_ETK_HELP = "Please follow the ETK install instructions and make sure that" \
"/home/etk/impinj_etk is in your PATH, or that the ETK_INSTALL_DIR is defined."

# The cap_gen tool may be in the PATH, the install dir, or in the current dir.
CAP_GEN_EXE = cap_gen.sh
CAP_GEN_IN_PATH=$(shell which $(CAP_GEN_EXE))
CAP_GEN_CWD=$(shell ls ./$(CAP_GEN_EXE) 2>/dev/null)
CAP_GEN_DEFAULT=$(shell ls $(ETK_DEFAULT_INSTALL_DIR)/$(CAP_GEN_EXE) 2>/dev/null)
ifneq (,$(CAP_GEN_IN_PATH))
    CAP_GEN=$(CAP_GEN_IN_PATH)
else
    ifneq (,$(ETK_INSTALL_DIR))
        CAP_GEN=$(ETK_INSTALL_DIR)/$(CAP_GEN_EXE)
    else
        ifneq (,$(CAP_GEN_DEFAULT))
            CAP_GEN=$(CAP_GEN_DEFAULT)
        else
            ifneq (,$(CAP_GEN_CWD))
                CAP_GEN=$(CAP_GEN_CWD)
            endif
        endif
    endif
endif


all: x86 arm

help:
    @echo Example use:
    @echo  ‘make arm’ to build the sample for on-reader use
    @echo  ‘make x86’ to build the sample for the (x86) host
    @echo  ‘make cap’ to build a CAP upgrade file

bin/speedwayr_x86:
    mkdir -p ./bin
    g++ \
        -m32 -Wno-write-strings \
        -I$(HEADER_DIR) \
        $(SOURCES) \
        -L$(MPNJ_LIB_DIR) -lltkcpp_x86 -lltkcppimpinj_x86 -lxml2_x86 \
        -L$(LIB_DIR) -ldl -lssl -lcrypto \
        -o bin/speedwayr_x86

x86: bin/speedwayr_x86

bin/speedwayr_arm: check_env
    mkdir -p ./bin
    arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ \
        -Wno-write-strings \
        -I$(HEADER_DIR) \
        $(SOURCES) \
        -L$(MPNJ_LIB_DIR) \
        -static -lltkcpp_atmel -lltkcppimpinj_atmel -lxml2_atmel \
        -lssl_atmel -lcrypto_atmel -ldl_atmel \
        -o bin/speedwayr_arm
    arm-none-linux-gnueabi-strip bin/speedwayr_arm

arm: bin/speedwayr_arm

cap: arm check_env
    $(CAP_GEN) -d cap_description.in -o speedwayr_cap.upg

clean:
    rm -rf bin/*
    rm -rf speedwayr_cap.upg

.PHONY: check_env
check_env:
    @if ! which $(CAP_GEN_EXE) > /dev/null && \
        [ ! -f $(ETK_INSTALL_DIR)/$(CAP_GEN_EXE) > /dev/null ] && \
        [ ! -f ./$(CAP_GEN_EXE) > /dev/null ]; then \
        echo "Failed to find $(CAP_GEN_EXE)."; \
        echo $(INSTALL_ETK_HELP); \
        exit 1; \
    fi
    @if ! which arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ > /dev/null; then \
        echo $(INSTALL_TOOL_HELP); \
        exit 1; \
    fi
```

Note:- 
- Added the -std=c++11 on each g++ in the Makefile as per the suggestion given by @Mikel Rychliski, and got the below error,

```
root@mindlogic-VirtualBox:/home/user/octane_etk_sample-6.0.0.240# make
mkdir -p ./bin
g++ \
    -m32 -Wno-write-strings -std = c++11 \
    -Iinclude \
    speedway_embedded_example.cpp \
    -Llib -lltkcpp_x86 -lltkcppimpinj_x86 -lxml2_x86 \
    -L/usr/bin -ldl -lssl -lcrypto \
    -o bin/speedwayr_x86
g++: error: =: No such file or directory
g++: error: c++11: No such file or directory
g++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-std’
Makefile:45: recipe for target 'bin/speedwayr_x86' failed
make: *** [bin/speedwayr_x86] Error 1
```

Note 2:
Without space while adding -std=c++11, got the errors as

```
    root@mindlogic-VirtualBox:/home/mindlogic/octane_etk_sample-6.0.0.240# make
mkdir -p ./bin
g++ \
    -m32 -Wno-write-strings -std=c++11 \
    -Iinclude \
    speedway_embedded_example.cpp \
    -Llib -lltkcpp_x86 -lltkcppimpinj_x86 -lxml2_x86 \
    -L/usr/bin -ldl -lssl -lcrypto \
    -o bin/speedwayr_x86
In file included from include/ltkcpp.h:32:0,
                 from speedway_embedded_example.cpp:19:
include/ltkcpp_base.h:97:5: error: ‘llrp_u16_t’ does not name a type
     llrp_u16_t                  m_nValue;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `-std=c++11` on each g++ command line:

```
g++ \
    -m32 -Wno-write-strings -std=c++11 \
    -I$(HEADER_DIR) \
    $(SOURCES) \
    -L$(MPNJ_LIB_DIR) -lltkcpp_x86 -lltkcppimpinj_x86 -lxml2_x86 \
    -L$(LIB_DIR) -ldl -lssl -lcrypto \
    -o bin/speedwayr_x86

arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ \
    -Wno-write-strings -std=c++11 \
    -I$(HEADER_DIR) \
    $(SOURCES) \
    -L$(MPNJ_LIB_DIR) \
    -static -lltkcpp_atmel -lltkcppimpinj_atmel -lxml2_atmel \
    -lssl_atmel -lcrypto_atmel -ldl_atmel \
    -o bin/speedwayr_arm
```

To avoid duplication, you could add `$(CXXFLAGS)` instead and set `CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11`. elsewere in the Makefile (as suggested by @stark). Most users of make expect that `g++` compilation rules will respect this variable.

Comment: Added on each -std=c++11 on each g++ and i got the error as mentioned in the post itself.

Comment: @MahamuthaM: No spaces before or after the `=`

Comment: added -std=c++11 without spaces, now got other error which has been attached in the post as Note 2

Comment: @MahamuthaM: That error appears unrelated to the compiler flags. You'll have to investigate the source code or contact the vendor

Comment: I have included the "CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11" in the top of Makefile. After that i didnt get Note 2 error which is mentioned in the post. Your response and other ones response make me to get this done.

Comment: @MahamuthaM if this solved your question please consider marking this as the correct answer and upvoting : )